# Preserving server objects over requests in a loopback 4 app to cache, within a middleware

Tags: node.js, rest, middleware, loopbackjs, loopback4

I have an application that is built in loopback4, a nodejs framework to build REST Api's.
Within that app I want to cache public certificates of various jwt token issuers to not request these with every api call. My problem is the sequence and each middleware get a new instance with every request.  While I could use something like redis, I wonder if I could achieve something similar without an extra service. I do not see any possibility to commit an object from the application that lasts longer than a single request, any ideas?

I assume the same would apply e.g. for express middlewares that do memory caching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue with creating a caching service that was created in the application.ts to the app:

```
import {CacheService} from './caching/cacheservice.service';
import {CacheServiceBindings} from './caching/keys';
[..]
this.add(createBindingFromClass(CacheService, {key: CacheServiceBindings.CACHE}));
```

and injected this in the sequence.ts constructor:

```
@inject(CacheServiceBindings.CACHE) protected cache: CacheService,
```

that way I am able to use this object persisting the whole application lifecycle in the sequence.